Tabulate dimensions of a folder of images
I have a folder of images that I would like to produce a table of widths and heights of. The closest solution I can find is the magick package, but the image_read only analyses one image at a time, whereas I have a folder of 500 images (e.g. Rooster001.png, Rooster002.png, etc). Are there any packages that summarises image file properties or at least tabulates these easily?
There is a similar past thread on this focused on speed of processing, but I can't replicate the code to function for my needs. For example, I tried the exifr package (per below), but have just now learned that the EXIF data has been scrubbed from my images.
library(exifr)
imagedims<-data.frame(file_path = list.files("./images", 
                                       pattern =".png$",
                                       full.names = TRUE,
                                       recursive = TRUE))

listofdims<-read_exif(imagedims$file_path,tags = c("ExifImageWidth", "ExifImageHeight"))

Thank you in advance!

What is dat? Don't you need imagedims$file_path in your final line?

Thanks Andrew for pointing that out! I've fixed it, but now the output I get is just a list of the file names, rather than the dimensions

I've figured it out, I think the images I have have the EXIF data scrubbed, so I will need to find another way to extract the dimensions

I have found a fairly easy solution using the magick package, using an answer from another thread with an adjacent question:
# List files

imagelist <- list.files(path = "./imagefolder/", pattern = ".png", 
                          full.names = T)

# Extract image info into a tibble

imageinfo <- image_info(image_read(imagelist))

# Print tibble

print(imageinfo)


On Linux (and maybe MacOS) use ImageMagick identify -format directly with system for image info; avoids RAM overload from loading images.
> read_img_info_dir <- \(path) {
+   info <- system(
+     sprintf('for img in %s/*.{jpg,png,gif}; do
+               identify -limit thread 4 \\
+                 -format "%%f,%%m,%%w,%%h,%%r,%%b,%%x,%%x\\n" "$img";
+             done', 
+             path), 
+     intern=TRUE) |>
+     strsplit(',') |> 
+     do.call(what='rbind.data.frame') |> 
+     setNames(c("file", "format", "width", "height", "colorspace", "bytes",
+                "xres", "yres")) |> 
+     within({
+       bytes=stringi::stri_replace_all_regex(
+         bytes,
+         paste0('(?<=\\d)', c('B', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB'), '$'),
+         c("*2^0", "*2^10", "*2^20", "*2^30"),
+         vectorize_all=FALSE
+       ) |> sapply(\(x) eval(parse(text=x))) |> round()
+       colorspace=trimws(colorspace)
+     }) |> 
+     type.convert(as.is=TRUE)
+ }

Processing a directory with 324 images averaged 9.82 secs.
> read_img_info_dir(path)
             file format width height             colorspace  bytes xres yres
1   image-001.png    PNG   424    234 DirectClass sRGB Matte  14132 37.8 37.8
2   image-002.png    PNG   367    217 DirectClass sRGB Matte  18198 37.8 37.8
3   image-003.png    PNG   501    322 DirectClass sRGB Matte  38007 37.8 37.8
4   image-004.png    PNG   148    153       DirectClass sRGB  15480 72.0 72.0
5   image-005.png    PNG  1406    792 DirectClass sRGB Matte 721938 72.0 72.0
6   image-006.jpg   JPEG   373    797       DirectClass sRGB  40217 72.0 72.0
[...]
319 image-319.png    PNG  1215    695 DirectClass sRGB Matte  49623 72.0 72.0
320 image-320.png    PNG   480    270 DirectClass Gray Matte   1340 72.0 72.0
321 image-321.png    PNG   387    108 DirectClass sRGB Matte  38791 72.0 72.0
322 image-322.png    PNG   731    953 DirectClass sRGB Matte  99421 72.0 72.0
323 image-323.png    PNG   480    270 DirectClass sRGB Matte  37759 72.0 72.0
324 image-324.png    PNG   720   1280       DirectClass sRGB  97880 72.0 72.0

Note, that ImageMagick has to be installed first.

Here is another way with a C language function to get the dimensions of the images. PNG files record the image's width and height as 4 bytes ints starting at offset 16, so just seek that location, read 8 bytes and convert to two 4-byte integers.
/* 
file: dimpng.c
*/
#include <R.h>
#include <Rinternals.h>

#define DIM_OFFSET 16
#define DIM_SIZE 8

SEXP dim_png(SEXP FileName) {
    FILE *fp;
    char *filename, buf[DIM_SIZE];
    SEXP Dim;
    R_len_t *pDim;

    if(!isString(FileName) || length(FileName) != 1)
        error("'FileName' is not a character string of length one.");
    filename = CHAR(STRING_ELT(FileName, 0));
    if((fp = fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL)
        error("Cannot open file '%s'\n", filename);

    fseek(fp, DIM_OFFSET, SEEK_SET);
    fread(&buf, sizeof(char), DIM_SIZE, fp);
    fclose(fp);

    PROTECT(Dim = allocVector(INTSXP, 2));
    pDim = INTEGER(Dim);
    pDim[0] = (buf[0] << 24) + (buf[1] << 16) + (buf[2] << 8) + (buf[3] << 0);
    pDim[1] = (buf[4] << 24) + (buf[5] << 16) + (buf[6] << 8) + (buf[7] << 0);
    UNPROTECT(1);
    return(Dim);
}

This function can be complied from within R with
args <- c("CMD", "SHLIB", "dimpng.c")
system2("R", args)

Now write a R wrapper, calling the function in a sapply loop, set the column names and the return value is a matrix with columns width and height.
# auxiliary functions to make loading the shared lib easier
dynLoad <- function(dynlib){
  dynlib <- paste0(dynlib, .Platform$dynlib.ext)
  dyn.load(dynlib)
}
dynUnload <- function(dynlib){
  dynlib <- paste0(dynlib, .Platform$dynlib.ext)
  dyn.unload(dynlib)
}

# this function loops through all the filenames passed to it.
dim_png <- function(x) {
  sapply(x, \(fl) .Call("dim_png", fl)) |>
    t() |>
    `colnames<-`(c("width", "height"))
}

# now load the C function and call the R function above
dynLoad("dimpng")
dim_png(imagedims$file_path)
dynUnload("C/dimpng")

